# Posting Gzipped data with curl

Tags: perl, curl, gzip

im trying to use the system curl to post gzipped data to a server but i keep ending up with strange errors

```
`curl -sS -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/gzip" --data-binary $data $url`
```

gives

```
curl: no URL specified!
```

and

```
`curl -sS -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/gzip" --data-binary "$data" $url`
```

gives

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the `"` is a step in the right direction, but you didn't consider that `$data` might contains `"`, `$`, etc. You could use [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aShellQuote) to address the issue.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote(
   curl => (
      '-sS',
      '-X' => 'POST',
      '-H' => 'Content-Type: application/gzip',
      '--data-binary' => $data,
      $url,
   ),
);

my $output = `$cmd`;
```

Or you could avoid the shell entirely.

```
my @cmd = (
   curl => (
      '-sS',
      '-X' => 'POST',
      '-H' => 'Content-Type: application/gzip',
      '--data-binary' => $data,
      $url,
   ),
);

open(my $pipe, '-|', @cmd) or die $!;
my $output = do { local $/; <$pipe> };
close($pipe);
```

Or if you didn't actually need to capture the output, the following also avoids the shell entirely:

```
system(
   curl => (
      '-sS',
      '-X' => 'POST',
      '-H' => 'Content-Type: application/gzip',
      '--data-binary' => $data,
      $url,
   ),
);
```

That said, I don't see how you can possibly send strings containing NUL bytes, something a gzipped file is likely to have. I think your approach is inherently flawed.

Do you know that `libcurl` (the guts of `curl`) can be accessed via [Net::Curl::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aCurl%3a%3aEasy)?

Comment: I was having troubles getting Net::Curl::Easy to properly validate ssl certs, so thats why I tried using the system curl

Comment: hum, they use the same library to do that!

Answer (score 4):

I did not succeed in getting curl to read the data straight from stdin, but process substitution did work, for example:

```
curl -sS -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/gzip" --data-binary @<(echo "Uncompressed data" | gzip) $url
```

This technique removes any need to having to write to a temporary file first.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your binary data contains all kind of trash, including quotes and null bytes, which confuse the shell. Try putting your data into some file and post that file.